# PyTorch Softmax Output Doesn't Sum to 1

Tags: pytorch, softmax

Cross posting [my question from the PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/torch-nn-functionals-softmax-does-not-sum-to-1/59516):

I started receiving negative KL divergences between a target Dirichlet distribution and my model’s output Dirichlet distribution. Someone online suggested that this might be indicative that the parameters of the Dirichlet distribution don’t sum to 1. I thought this was ridiculous since the output of the model is passed through

`output = F.softmax(self.weights(x), dim=1)`

But after looking into it more closely, I found that `torch.all(torch.sum(output, dim=1) == 1.)` returns False! Looking at the problematic row, I see that it is `tensor([0.0085, 0.9052, 0.0863], grad_fn=<SelectBackward>)`. But `torch.sum(output[5]) == 1.` produces `tensor(False)`.

What am I misusing about softmax such that output probabilities do not sum to 1?

This is PyTorch version 1.2.0+cpu. Full model is copied below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F



def assert_no_nan_no_inf(x):
    assert not torch.isnan(x).any()
    assert not torch.isinf(x).any()


class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.weights = nn.Linear(
            in_features=2,
            out_features=3)

    def forward(self, x):
        output = F.softmax(self.weights(x), dim=1)
        assert torch.all(torch.sum(output, dim=1) == 1.)
        assert_no_nan_no_inf(x)
        return output
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? The "problematic" row does sum to 1: `sum([0.0085, 0.9052, 0.0863])`

Comment: Maybe you should consider an assert that tolerates small precision errors, such as: `s = torch.sum(output, dim=1); torch.allclose(s, torch.ones_like(s))`

Comment: The row does. But Python + Pytorch says the row doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that tolerating floating point errors might create negative KL divergences (if the densities no longer sum to 1).

Comment: I understand. I would recommended deleting and posting a new one with a different perspective, then. Right now it is misleading.

Comment: Floating point errors are simply a fact of computing. If your algorithm blows up because of these then something in your algorithm has major stability or conditioning issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably due to the floating point numerical errors due to finite precision.

Instead of checking strict inequality you should check the mean square error or something to be within an acceptable limit.

For ex: I get `torch.norm(output.sum(dim=1)-1)/N` to be less than `1e-8`. N is the batch size.

Comment: Sure. My problem is that tolerating floating point errors might create negative KL divergences (if the densities no longer sum to 1).

Comment: I am not sure what is the exact formula you are using for KL, but all I can say it can possibly be made more numerically safe.

Comment: Should I tell that to PyTorch's developers then? :)

Comment: I am not sure about this as I can't see how not summing to 1 is the reason for the problem. You would be using \sum p_i log p_i/q_i right? to compute KL right?